# Twilio "Send and Wait for Reply" Keeps Previous Parameter

Tags: twilio, twilio-flow

I am trying to implement a simple "go back" button in a Twilio Flow for Whatsapp. So, the objective is to have the user either enter a text, or they could choose to go back to the previous question.

The way I have done it is to check the ButtonPayload and see if it is blank, but the problem is that once the user chooses to go back, the ButtonPayload never changes until the flow is done.

What is the solution?

Implementing a subflow works great, but I can only add 50 subflow widgets, and I think I need more than 50 widgets.

Comment: Can you add post a screenshot of your flow so it's easier to understand what you got? Also, what do you mean with ButtonPayload?

Comment: Ok. But is it possible to add more than 50 Run Subflow widgets?

Comment: The docs mentions all [limitations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/studio-faq#flow-limits) and it doesn't seem to restrict the number of subflows